# What is the time complexity of following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Given a sequence of n integers, A.
To find the sum of the sequence we are following the following recursive algorithm, we make a new sequence B of size n/2 where B[i] = A[2*i] + A[2*i + 1] for i from 0 to n/2 - 1 and we replace A with B. When size of A is 1, we return the element itself.

Shouldn't the time complexity be calcualted as follows?

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n/2)
or
T(n) = T(n/4) + O(n/4) + O(n/2)
or
T(n) = O(1) + O(2) + O(4) + ... + O(n/4) + O(n/2)
```

At this point I am not sure if I am doing it correctly and what this value should be equal to. I am assuming O(nlgn)

How do I arrive at the solution ? Also, using master theorem is giving me O(n), I am not sure if I am applying master theorem properly. Can someone please guide me here?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your "algorithm" is, but note that if summing a sequence takes longer than O(n), you're doing something wrong ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First observe that

```
O(1) + O(2) + O(4) + ... + O(n/4) + O(n/2) =
  O(1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n/4 + n/2)
```

Then you could recognize here the sum of a geometric progression. Assuming `n = 2^m` (2 to the power of m)

```
  1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^(m-2) + 2^(m-1) = 2^m = n
```

Therefore your method gives you T(n) = O(n). This is in an agreement with the master theorem.